# Rails: HT switch Parent of Child objects when Deleting Parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, belongs-to

I'm building a small app with Rails 4.2.6. Suppose I have the
following classes:

```
class Caseworker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cases
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :caseworkers
end
```

... with views to create, view, update, and destroy them each. I then
create multiple Caseworkers and assign multiple Cases to them.

Currently, if I attempt to delete a Caseworker, I'll get an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

No problem, that's to be expected.

In some CMSes, though, if a user
attempts to destroy an object with such dependencies, you can present
them with the option to assign the objects to another parent, or
destroy them. Is there a standard way, in Rails, to offer this functionality? Otherwise, it seems like I will need to put a `before_destroy` clause in the Caseworker controller... is this true? I'm not afraid to write such a method if need be, but I'd rather not reinvent this wheel if it's there for me to use somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one of `dependent: :destroy` or `dependent: :nullify` to the `has_many` statement, depending on whether you want the children deleted or to have their foreign key field nulled.

For example, to delete the Cases belonging to a Caseworker being deleted you could use:

```
class Caseworker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cases, dependent: :destroy
end
```

To my knowledge Rails has no way to reassign children to a different parent - you'd have to write code to do that yourself.